# Найти позицию элемента в выборке по уникальному номеру

Tags: php, mysql

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться. Своих навыков мне не хватило, решил обратиться к вам за помощью.
У меня есть запрос-выборка игроков с сортировкой по кол-ву опыта.

```
SELECT `id`, `exp` FROM `players` ORDER BY `exp` DESC;
```

Но мне требуется составить запрос, чтобы узнать на какой позиции в выборке находится игрок со своим, уникальным id.

Например такая таблица:

```
    id exp
 1. 1 15
 2. 2 30
 3. 3 20
 4. 4 45
 5. 5 1
```

Допустим такой результат выборки:

```
    id exp
 1. 4 45
 2. 2 30
 3. 3 20
 4. 1 15
 5. 5 1
```

Мне требуется составить составить запрос, чтобы узнать на каком месте в выборке находится игрок, например, с id=1, в данном случае ответ был бы 4.
Сразу хочу сказать спасибо всем откликнувшимся!

Comment: `dense_rank()`  если версия mysql позволяет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

первое, что пришло в голову: посчитать id  с меньшим exp, чем у заданного

```
SELECT count(`id`)+1 as rank
  FROM `players` 
  WHERE `exp` < (
    SELECT `exp`
      FROM `players`
      WHERE `id` = $id 
  )
```

по крайней мере одна очевидная проблема - что такое "место". Если есть несколько игроков с одинаковым exp, то как распределять "места" между ними? Может ли, например, быть два игрока на втором месте? Тогда результат будет неправильный

UPDATE

```
select count(id)+1 as rank
  from players p 
     join 
       (
        SELECT `exp` 
          FROM  `players` 
          WHERE `id` = $id 
       ) as my
   where p.exp < my.exp 
         or (p.exp = my.exp and id < $id)
```

Comment: Только нужно `exp <= (`... места начинаются с единицы как бы.

Comment: @Akina вообще, это тоже вопрос про двух равных, скорее `SELECT count(`id`)+1 as rank` Пока поправил так

Comment: Предположительно данный вариант работает, а как сюда добавить обратную сортировку ORDER BY `exp` DESC? :)

Comment: он сравнением задается. Когда спрашивается `exp` <

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо большое даже за это решение! Но осталось решить проблему с одинаковым количеством exp. Например идут подряд игроки с id=465(Место 80, exp 495) и id=1657(Место 81, exp 495). При поиске их двоих результат один - 80

Comment: каков критерий  что не наоборот? по id?

Comment: Пожалуй да, приоритет в позиции у меньшего ID

Comment: просто в вашей сортированной выборке mysql последовательность для одинаковых номеров не гарантирует, так что, что бы мы не сочинили, может не совпасть, если только вы в запросе не будете писать `order by exp desc, id`

Comment: Хорошо, это не проблема, в самой таблице order by exp desc есть, сейчас добавим id

Comment: Гарантию приоритета меньшего id добавил, визуально результат не изменился. Подскажите пожалуйста, как доработать запрос, чтобы получить верную позицию? :)

Comment: я сейчас на телефоне, приеду напишу, если никто раньше не ответит. думаю, надо к этому числу прибавить кол-во  id с таким же exp и меньших нашего

Comment: Спасибо за идею! Свой вариант реализовал, но также подожду вашего. Вдруг он окажется более оптимизирован :)

Comment: Я обновил ответ

Comment: Отлично! Большое спасибо за помощь! Пусть удача наградит вас за отзывчивость! :)

Comment: @Svyatoy я тут глянул на свой вчерашний ответ и понял, что написал нечто странное :) вот, поправил

Comment: Поправил. Спасибо ещё раз!